# PDO valid characters for placeholders

Tags: php, pdo

In PHP with PDO, what characters are we limited to using. I've tried looking in the documentation and online but to no avail.

I did find a post where a user had used a hypen in the name which broke the query. I'm writing a function that dynamically generates these names and since hyphens are no nos, I was wondering if there was a list of alternatives.

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

So in this example what characters would be allowed in the string ':colour'?

Comment: Im not sure specifically what the limitations are but alphanum and underscores have never failed me :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The easiest way to find out, is to just check the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5638fafa665899523861a12966b42a9c609a1664/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.re#L48):

```
BINDCHR     = [:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+;
```

You can use alphanumeric + underscore.

Comment: Just looking at the source I can see bugs in there... their comment expression is wrong. `--` must be followed by whitespace, not just any non-linebreak char.

Comment: Hasn't changed for [PHP 5.6](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.re#49) if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 10):

If I read the [PDO SQL parser source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.re) correctly, it's alphanumeric characters plus underscore.