# What's wrong with my PDO Insert statement?

Tags: php, pdo

Here's my SQL statement:

```
protected static $_SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO location
(host_id, street, suburb, region, post_code, country, phone, email,
timezone, longitude, latitude, is_main)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

I prepare the statement as follows:

```
static::$_PDOSInsert = self::$_PDO->prepare(static::$_SQLInsert);
```

After preparing an array with 12 values, I execute the statement with:

```
static::$_PDOSInsert->execute($array);
```

I then get the following warning:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in...

So, what am I doing wrong???

EDIT: Here's the array:

```
(
    [host_id] => 15
    [street] => Street 15
    [suburb] => Suburb 15
    [region] => Region 15
    [post_code] => Post Code 15
    [country] => AU
    [phone] => 12341234
    [email] => asfd@email.com
    [timezone] => 1
    [longitude] => 123
    [latitude] => 234
    [is_main] => 1
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" Inserting data in Yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874383/invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined-inserting-data-in-yii)

Comment: `parameter was not defined`, maybe you forgot to define one of your parameters in the array? I'd use associative placeholders as `:host_id` instead of a dozen of `?`s to better track your parameters.

Comment: @mario: I'm not using named parameters

Comment: Aren't there missing quotes around some of your array values?

Comment: @KimPrince, Fabricio's suggestion is to start using named parameters.

Comment: @Sebas, this is the output from print_r

Comment: do `->execute(array_values($array));` verify the order matches the query, though...

Comment: @chris, that worked.  Why?  You should write this up as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdo is really picky about the array you give to execute(). If you used unnamed placeholders like `?`, it wants a numerically indexed array, and it must start at index 0.