# Whats wrong with my PDO mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is my code

```
$sql3= "select * 
        from comments 
        where status=:status  
        limit=:limit 
        offset=:offset 
        order by time desc";
$query3= $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$query3->bindValue(":status",'n');
$query3->bindValue(":limit",$per_page);
$query3->bindValue(":offest",$offset);
$query3->execute();
$comments=$query3->fetchall();
```

Here comments is my table name status and time is two column in my table . Whenever I run this code  , It shows a warning

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\parlament\user\logged_in_area.php

What does this mean ?

Comment: For starters, you're missing `AND` or `OR` keyword between your conditions

Comment: what kind of query is that? 1.limit is not in the end. 2.what is offset?

Comment: Don't use limit=:limit  change it to limit :limit and same as for offset..

Comment: You guys need to read the manual ~ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: aha,those are fields in db. Now i get it. So you are missing AND as asprin said, + limit is reserved word in SQL.

Comment: One more thing that seemingly hasn't been mentioned: your query uses a placeholder `:offset`, but you are binding a value to `:offest` instead.

Comment: @DCoder and **that** is the direct cause of OP's error :)

Comment: Durn, conused the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874383/invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined-inserting-data it have to be. Not a big deal but for sake of clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends of what are `limit` and `offset`.

### If they're columns names...

- You can't use these reserved keywords for column names without backticks
- You need to add a `AND` / `OR` operator between your lines

```
$sql3= "select * 
        from comments 
        where status=:status  
        and `limit`=:limit 
        and `offset`=:offset 
        order by time desc";
$query3= $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$query3->bindValue(":status", 'n');
$query3->bindValue(":limit", $per_page);
$query3->bindValue(":offest", $offset);
$query3->execute();
$comments=$query3->fetchall();
```

### If they're keywords...

- The syntax is `LIMIT <n>`, not `LIMIT = <n>` (same for `OFFSET`)
- It better to specify their type with `PDO::PARAM_INT` (same for `OFFSET`)
- `ORDER BY` must be added before `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

```
$sql3= "select * 
        from comments 
        where status=:status 
        order by time desc 
        limit :limit 
        offset :offset";
$query3= $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$query3->bindValue(":status", 'n');
$query3->bindValue(":limit", (int)$per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query3->bindValue(":offset", (int)$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query3->execute();
$comments=$query3->fetchall();
```

Comment: if they are keywords, should not limit and offset go after ORDER BY?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic You're right, I just realised it. Thanks !

Comment: @zessx np, i know c/p problems :)

Comment: @Phil when i put order by after limit in my queries i always get sql error. maybe it changed in some new versions :D

Comment: @BojanKovacevic Just tested, you are right. `ORDER BY` **must** come before `LIMIT`

Comment: in face, in single query as i know LIMIT goes after all other parts (WHERE, ORDER BY,GROUP BY,HAVING ...)

Comment: Your code works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding my answer because nobody has mentioned this specific part yet...

MySQL is **very** picky about the data type of `LIMIT` parameters. You pretty much need to use `bindParam(':limit', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT)`. I assume the same for `OFFSET`.

So, in summary

```
// because E_WARNING level errors are insufficient
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `status` = :status ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
$stmt->bindValue(':status', 'n');
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT); // spelt "offset"
$stmt->execute();
$comments = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
$sql3= "select * 
        from comments 
        where status = ?  
        limit ?
        offset ? 
        order by time desc";
$query3= $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$query3->execute(array('n',$per_page,$offset));
$comments=$query3->fetchall();
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about that but I think that PDO::bindValue / bindParam works with variable references. You cannot set a static value as parameter. 
Try to replace

```
$query3->bindValue(":status",'n');
```

by

```
$n_value = 'n';
$query3->bindValue(":status",$n_value);
```

You also forgot the "AND" Keyword between your conditions

Comment: Though correct, this is not the full answer as the query will still fail

Comment: Actually, this is **not** correct. `bindValue` specifically works with non-references

Comment: @Phil Ahh..right...didn't notice the `bindValue` part

Answer (score -2):

You're missing the `AND` or `OR` keyword in statement. Also, `LIMIT` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-5.5.39), you'll need to backtick it or rename it to something else if you don't want to do that.

Comment: I agree -- explain. He is right. The way OP has formatted this, limit is just another column in his table.

Comment: I'd say OP is using `LIMIT` as per standard use

Comment: I assumed that `limit` in this case was a column, since he also has an `offset` column. If the limit was at the very end, I wouldn't have put said what I did.

Comment: Check the manual. `LIMIT ... OFFSET` is completely valid

Comment: @Phil I'll be damned. You're right.

Answer (score -4):

```
$sql3= "select * 
        from comments 
        where status = ?  
        limit= ?
        offset= ? 
        order by time desc";
$query3= $pdo->prepare($sql3);
$query3->bindValue(1,'n');
$query3->bindValue(2,$per_page);
$query3->bindValue(3,$offset);
$query3->execute();
$comments=$query3->fetchall();
```

Comment: You're treating limit as just another column inside the table. whilst you probably meant that it's the `LIMIT` keyword meant to limit results.