# PDO doesn't recognize a parameter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, parameters

I have this query:

```sql
INSERT INTO user ( username , password , role )
SELECT
  CONCAT( :username1 , "-" , ABS( REPLACE( (
    SELECT username FROM user
    WHERE username LIKE :username2
    ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
  ), :username3, "" ) ) + 1 ) AS username,
  :password,
  :role
```

In php I have this code for binding values:

```
$dbp = $db->prepare( $query );
for( $i = 1 ; $i <= 3 ; $i++ ){
        $dbp->bindValue( ':username' . $i , ( $i == 2 ? 'test%' : 'test' ) );
}
$dbp->bindValue( ':password' , '0' );
$dbp->bindValue( ':role' , 'test' );
$dbp->execute();
```

I have in the query 5 parameters:

```
:username1 , :username2 , :username3 , :password , :role
```

and each of everyone of them are assigned with the bindValue function.

Hovewer it triggers this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]:
Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in [...]
PDOStatement->bindValue(':username1', 'test') #1 {main} thrown in [...]
```

But the parameter do exists in my query and in my for loop. Can't I use a parameter in the CONCAT function?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874383/invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined-inserting-data) link, however, doesn't help me:

> 1) The :parameter name does not match the bind by mistake (typo?)

As I said, every parameter is matched: i echoed right before every bindValue, and every parameter was written correctly.

> 2) Completely forgetting to add the bindValue()

5 parameters, 5 bindValues , 5 echos with right matching

Third point in not for my question.

Comment: Have you var_dump()ed `$query` right before `prepare()`?

Comment: simple test: if for whatever crazy reason mysql DIDN'T allow placeholders in a concat() call, try binding to `:username3` first, without your loop. e.g. call bind() manually, without the loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are [hundreds similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Invalid%20parameter%20number%3A%20parameter%20was%20not%20defined) on this site already. **Not a single one of them discovered something mysterious about PDO binding yet.** All were caused by a simple typographic error. No exceptions.

You can use parameter in any part of query, as long as it is representing complete and single data literal.