# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined error pdo

Tags: php, pdo

```
$txtmemberid = $_POST['txtmemberid'];
$txtname = $_POST['txtname'];
$txtphoneno = $_POST['txtphoneno'];
$txtmembertype = $_POST['txtmembertype'];

$query = "insert into member(member_id, name, ph_no, member_type) values(:member_id, :name, :ph_no, :member_type)";

try{
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare($query);

    $stmt -> bindParam(':member_id', $txtmemberid);
    $stmt -> bindParam(': name', $txtname);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':ph_no', $txtphoneno);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':member_type', $txtmembertype);

    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

Comment: There's a pretty obvious typo on the second call to `bindParam`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874383/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is more than likely on this line:

```
$stmt -> bindParam(': name',$txtname);
```

You have extraneous whitespace between `:` and `name`, change it to this:

```
$stmt -> bindParam(':name',$txtname);
```