# function update using pdo in php error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having trouble with my fonction "update" using PDO with php.

Error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' on line 25
```

any one can help please?

```
function update($table,$data,$id){

  global $conn;
  $resultstr = array();
  foreach ($data as $keys => $value) {
    $resultstr[] = $keys."=:".$keys;
  }

  $values = implode(",",$resultstr);
  $sql ="Update ".$table." SET ".$values."WHERE id=:id";

   $query =  $conn->prepare($sql);

   $query->bindParam(':id',$id);

   foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        $query->bindValue(':'.$key,$val); 
   }
   $updateData = $query->execute();

   return $updateData;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" Inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874383/invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined-inserting-data)

Comment: you should put a space before `WHERE`

Comment: thank u mr. karsten koop it worked for me....