# Get an array of arrays in PHP with a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, symfony

I am working on Symfony 3.4 in PHP 5.6.

Here is the context of my problem:

I have an "information" table that contains several lines. I want to sort these lines and display them according to a certain column called "Zone". So the goal is to have for example

"Zone 1"
* Lines of information corresponding to this area "
"Zone 2"
* Lines of information corresponding to this area "
...

I realized my functions in the Repository, and I also made the layout under Twig. Everything worked. All I had to do was optimize my code on the controller to make it cleaner.

My idea was therefore:

1. Retrieve an array containing all the existing distinct areas by a query.
2. Loop on this array using each value of the array as a parameter for the SQL query that retrieves the rows corresponding to the passed field and retrieve them in an array variable
3. Make an array_push () of the array of each zone, in another array that will contain the array of each zone.

But I can't. This is my code

Repository :

```
public function getInformationsZone($zone)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("i")
        ->where("i.zone = :zone")
        ->orderBy("i.updatedAt","DESC")
        ->orderBy("i.criticite","DESC")
        ->setParameter('zone',$zone);

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    public function getZonesActives()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("i")
        ->select("i.zone")
        ->distinct(true);

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

controller

```
/**
     * Lists all information entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="informations_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $information = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->findAll();


        $listZones = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getZonesActives();
        $tabInfos = array();

        foreach($listZones as $key=>$value)
        {
            $zone = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone($value);
            array_push($tabInfos,$zone);
        }



// This is what i did just before

      /*  $infosZone1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 1");
        $infosZone2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 2");
        $infosZone3 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 3");

        $tabInfos = array($infosZone1,$infosZone2,$infosZone3);*/

        return $this->render('information/index.html.twig', array(
           /* 'information' => $information,
            'infosZone1'=> $infosZone1,
            'infosZone2'=> $infosZone2,
            'infosZone3'=> $infosZone3,*/
            'tabInfos'=>$tabInfos,
        ));
    }
```

I've this error :

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT i0_.id AS id_0, i0_.contenu AS contenu_1, i0_.updated_at AS updated_at_2, i0_.zone AS zone_3, i0_.titre AS titre_4, i0_.criticite AS criticite_5 FROM information i0_ WHERE i0_.zone = ? ORDER BY i0_.criticite DESC' with params ["Zone 1"]:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" Inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874383/invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined-inserting-data)

Comment: Dump `$value` parameter in the loop and see the actual value of it. If it's returning only a string like`Zone 1`.

Comment: Using  $zone = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone($value); 

I have : array:1 [▼
  "zone" => "Zone 1"
]

Comment: It's okay, i updated ($value) by ($value['zone']. It's work, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$zone = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone($value);
```

With this:

```
$zone = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')
    ->getInformationsZone($value->getZone());
```

You are passing the all zone entity to the `getInformationsZone` method.

So to get the title of the zone, you must call the getter of the zone.

`$value` to `$value->getZone();`

---

Edit: So, just change `$value->getZone()` to `$value['zone'];`

Comment: I updated my code. But I have this error :

Error: Call to a member function getZone() on array

My getZonesActives() function return a string array, not an objects array :/

Comment: @AgarioFR Updated the codes. Just see the last line.