# Trouble getting PDO delete statement to execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble getting a form to post a variable and then have my PDO statement execute a delete. I do know that the variable $resulting[WID] does have the correct value stored in it in my form. The problem is lies in passing the variable from this form to the code below to execute the delete statement. The error am getting is: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

//here is the php/PDO code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
 $the_WID = $_POST['WID'];
 echo "here is the WID" . $the_WID;

 $dlt = "DELETE FROM writing WHERE writing.WID = :writing.WID";
 $stmtdlt = $dbh->prepare($dlt);
 $stmtdlt->bindParam(':writing.WID', $the_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                           
 $stmtdlt->execute(); 
 }
```

//here is the form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
<input TYPE="hidden" name="remove" VALUE="<?php $resulting[WID]; ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `$the_WID = $_POST['WID'];` should be `$the_WID = $_POST['remove'];`.
2. You need to echo your value: `value="<?php echo $resulting[WID]; ?>"`
3. From [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809951/pdo-valid-characters-for-placeholders), it appears that you cannot use `.` in a placeholder:

> BINDCHR     = [:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+;
>
> You can use alphanumeric + underscore.

Change your PHP to:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    $the_WID = $_POST['remove'];
    echo "here is the WID" . $the_WID;

    $dlt = "DELETE FROM writing WHERE writing.WID = :writingWID";
    $stmtdlt = $dbh->prepare($dlt);
    $stmtdlt->bindParam(':writingWID', $the_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                           
    $stmtdlt->execute(); 
}
```

and your HTML form to:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
<input type="hidden" name="remove" value="<?php echo $resulting[WID]; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Well, I have been using writing.ID successfully in other PDO queries on the same page even. That said, I no longer get the error after doing what you said, although the value is still not being passed to $the_WID in $the_WID = $_POST['WID'];

Comment: Isn't the POST name `remove` from `<input TYPE="hidden" **name="remove"**...`? so `$the_WID = $_POST['remove'];` will have your delete value.

Comment: Also, `VALUE="<?php $resulting[WID]; ?>"` wont give you a value. It should be `VALUE="<?php echo $resulting[WID]; ?>"` :)

Comment: It works!!! An odd thing...I am echoing the $  and the value is should be 76. It echoes WID76. I don't care at all because it is obviously getting the correct record and then deleting it, but I'm surprised it works as WID76...I would think it would need it to just be 76, no? And do you have any idea why I can't use :writing.WID for this PDO statement when it works for others? Is DELETE different somehow in this regard? Also, I see that I need to refresh the page to see the delete go though. Not the case with the inserts when people add a WID text. Why is refresh only needed for this approach?

Comment: @hjpotter92 when I add the quotes it messes things up. Got it working just the way misterManSam proposed. Might be because of how he suggested doing writingWID instead of writing.WID (which wasn't working).

Comment: @jaw I don't know about the page refresh, but the `:writing.WID` could possibly work now that the rest of your code is fixed. The error could possibly just be a warning... That you should follow :)