# PDO - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo

I have used multiple forms on the site having the exact same config however, i'm specifically facing issue with this form.

**Source code:**

```
<?php

if (!$_POST['assessment-occupation'] || !$_POST['assessment-highest-qualification'] || !$_POST['assessment-experience']) {
    echo "<p>Please supply all of the data!</p>";
    exit;
} else {
    require('db-connection.php');
    //require('file-upload-script.php');
    try {  
        session_start();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE visa SET job_title= :assessment-occupation, Qualifications= :assessment-highest-qualification, experience= :assessment-experience, comments= :assessment-comments WHERE id= :id");

        // escape variables for security
        $stmt->bindParam(':assessment-occupation', $_POST['assessment-occupation']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':assessment-highest-qualification', $_POST['assessment-highest-qualification']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':assessment-experience', $_POST['assessment-experience']);
        //$stmt->bindParam(':file_upload', $target_file);
        $stmt->bindParam(':assessment-comments', $_POST['assessment-comments']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION["regId"]);

        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check `$_POST['assessment-comments']`

Comment: Post your `form code` and value of `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: My guess was that named placeholders can't have hyphens in their names. This thread seems to support that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809951/pdo-valid-characters-for-placeholders.

Comment: What dstudeba said is right, try to check it as well.