# PDO / MySQL: Underscore ('_') wildcard in PHP seems escaped by default

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping, wildcard

In my MSQL table, one row has the column *code* as "1001000**1810**26".

My PHP script is only interested in the bold part (**1810**), and I use the underscore wildcards (_) for the other characters of *code*.

But: It doesn't work with PDO (0 results)! On the other hand, if I write the `SELECT` code manually into phpMyAdmin, it works well (1 result).

Here is the PDO/PHP-code (which is *not* working):

```
$code = '_______1810__'; 
$preparequery = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE code LIKE :code';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($preparequery);
$stmt->bindValue("code", $code);
$y = $stmt->rowCount();

echo '<p>We have '.$y.' row(s).</p>'; // We have 0 row(s).
```

The query in phpMyAdmin works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE code LIKE '_______1810__'
```

This gives me 1 result, as expected.

What could be wrong with the PHP code (PDO)? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am not sure if it may have something to do with what is mentioned there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809951/pdo-valid-characters-for-placeholders according to which PDO placeholders (e.g. ":code") allow "alphanumeric + **underscore**" characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code LIKE CONCAT('_______', :code, '__')
```

This way you don't need to worry how the placeholders work. Also the PHP side will be a little more simplified.