# How to find parameters in PDO query by regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have a sql query like below:

```
select * from tbl_test where id=:id and name=:name
```

now I want to extract all variables from above string. for this reason I want to use `preg_match()` function in php. but I don't know how to write that regular experssion.

can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: There are no variables in the query. You want the placeholders? `:\w+` should do it for you I think (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809951/pdo-valid-characters-for-placeholders)

Comment: consider :variable in query as a variable. I want to find all :id and :name.

Comment: Provided regex should do that..did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pattern `/(\w+)=(:\w+)/` that match string before and after `=`

```
$str = "select * from tbl_test where id=:id and name=:name";
preg_match_all("/(\w+)=(:\w+)/", $str, $m);
print_r($m[2]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => :id
    [1] => :name
)
```

Also you can use `array_combine()` to create key/value array

```
$arr = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [id] => :id
    [name] => :name
)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/LSFJb)