# What are the rules for named parameters in PDO?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

I assume there's more to it than just a colon followed by any amount of any non-whitespace characters.

I believe this is PDO specific, but if it is SQL specific, I am using Oracle SQL.

I'm trying to compose a regex to match all named parameters in a query, so I need the exact rules, eg, max length, allowed characters, does it have to start with an alphabet char, et cetera.

I was unable to find the answer on the manual pages for [PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [PDO::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), or [PDO::bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), or from a quick Google search.

A link to some kind of spec would be great, if anyone knows where to find it.

Comment: Think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809951/pdo-valid-characters-for-placeholders is the answer.

Comment: Thanks Nigel! I closed the question as duplicate, will leave this one here to add visibility to the other question. I knew that if there was an answer Common Sense would know it.